unexpected behaviour in implementaion of event emiter class
I have tried to write an eventEmitter class following explanation on these link

but when I wrote my own code


class EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    this.listeners = {};
  }

  addListener(eventName, fn) {
    this.listeners[eventName] = this.listeners[eventName] || [];
    this.listeners[eventName].push(fn)
    return this;
  }

  on(eventName, fn) {
    this.addListener(eventName, fn);
    return this;
  }

  removeListener(eventName, fn) {
    if (!this.listeners[eventName] || this.listeners[eventName].length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const index = this.listeners[eventName].indexOf(fn);
    this.listeners[eventName].splice(index, 1);
  }

  off(eventName, fn) {
    this.removeListener(eventName, fn);
  }

  once(eventName, fn) {
    this.listeners[eventName] = this.listeners[eventName] || [];
    const onceWrapper = (...args) => {
      fn(...args);
      this.removeListener(eventName, onceWrapper);
    }
    this.listeners[eventName].push(onceWrapper);
    return this;
  }

  emit(eventName, ...args) {
    this.listeners[eventName].forEach(fn => {
      fn(...args);
    });
    return this;
  }
}

const obj = new EventEmitter();

const c1 = () => {
  console.log("Callback 1");
}
const c2 = () => {
  console.log("Callback 2");
}
const c3 = (x) => {
  console.log(`Callback ${x}`);
}

obj.once("foo", c1);
obj.once("foo", c2);
obj.once("foo", c3);

obj.emit("foo", 3)



the output was logged
Callback 1
Callback 3

not
Callback 1
Callback 2
Callback 3

I printed the listeners["foo"].length before calling emit() and after was first 3 then 1 it acted like skipping c2. I do not know the reason which does not make forEach loop on all items and I also tried to add more callbacks but also it dose not call all functions

You're deleting from the listeners array while you're iterating over it. After you emit execute listeners[0], you splice it out, so all the later listeners shift their indexes down. Then you execute listeners[1], which was the original listeners[2].

Make a copy of the listeners array and iterate over that.
